# Show list of requirements including those that are complete

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am having trouble with this seemingly simple select query.

I have three tables, a badge table, a requirements table, and a table showing which scouts have completed which requirements. I would like to be able to enter in a badge # and scout ID and get a list back of all the requirements for the badge I enter and the completion date for the requirements the specified scout has completed.

Here are my tables:

badge table

```
__________________________
|id|badgeName  |rank     |
--------------------------  
|1 |First Aid  |Navigator|
|2 |Woods Tools|Navigator|
|3 |Aquatics   |Navigator|
|4 |Camping    |Navigator|
--------------------------
```

Requirements table

```
____________________________________________________________________
id |badgeid|requirementnum|requirementstep|description              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|1 |1      |11            |a              |Requirement 11a First Aid|
|2 |1      |11            |               |Requirement 11 First Aid |
|3 |1      |11            |b              |Requirement 11b First Aid|
|4 |1      |11            |c              |Requirement 11c First Aid|
|5 |1      |11            |d              |Requirement 11d First Aid|
|6 |1      |11            |e              |Requirement 11e First Aid|
|7 |1      |11            |f              |Rquirement 11f First Aid |
|8 |1      |11            |g              |Requirement 11g First Aid|
|9 |1      |1             |               |Requirement 1 First Aid  |
|10|1      |1             |a              |Requirement 1a First Aid |
|11|1      |1             |b              |Requirement 1b First Aid |
|12|1      |2             |               |Requirement 2 First Aid  |
|13|1      |2             |a              |Requirement 2a First Aid |
|14|3      |1             |               |Requirement 1 Aquatics   |
|15|3      |2             |               |Requirement 2 awuatics   |
|16|3      |3             |a              |Requirement 3a Aquatics  |
|17|3      |3             |b              |Requirement 3b Aquatics  |
|18|4      |1             |               |Requirement 1Camping     |
|19|4      |2             |a              |Requirement 2a Camping   |
|20|4      |2             |b              |Requirement 2b camping   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Trailman/Requirements table

```
________________________________________________
|id|requirementid|trailmanid|complete  |comments|
-------------------------------------------------
|1 |1            |1         |2014-01-01|JO      |
|2 |2            |1         |2014-01-01|JO      |
|3 |3            |1         |2016-01-01|CS      |
|4 |18           |4         |2016-01-01|CS      |
|5 |19           |4         |2016-01-01|CS      |
|6 |20           |4         |2014-02-10|JO      |
|7 |18           |1         |2016-06-12|null    |
|8 |14           |2         |null      |null    |
|9 |15           |2         |null      |null    |
-------------------------------------------------
```

So, if I am trying to show all the camping badge requirements and the completed date for any of the requirements by trailmanid = 1 I was doing something like this:

```
select badgename, requirementnum, requirementstep, description,firstname, complete
from badges inner join requirements on badges.id = requirements.badgeid
left join trailmenrequirements on requirements.[id] = trailmenrequirements.requirementid
left join trailmen on trailmenrequirements.[trailmanid] = trailmen.id
where (trailmanid = 1 or trailmanid is null)
and badgeid = 4
```

This doesn't get me what I want, it only pulls back the one camping requirement that trailmanid = 1 has completed.If I do some other combination, like look for the First Aid badge for trailmanid = 1 then it seems to pull back the correct data. I think it has to do with whether any scout has a certain requirements completed or not.

After spending WAY too much time with it and 100's of permutation I figured I would enlist the experts. Can anyone help?

The expected results to the query above would be:

```
+-----------+----------------+-----------------+------------------------+------------+------------+
| badgename | requirementnum | requirementstep | description            | trailmanid | complete   |
+-----------+----------------+-----------------+------------------------+------------+------------+
| Camping   | 1              | null            | Requirement 1 camping  | 1          | 2016-06-12 |
+-----------+----------------+-----------------+------------------------+------------+------------+
| Camping   | 2              | a               | Requirement 2a Camping |            |            |
+-----------+----------------+-----------------+------------------------+------------+------------+
| Camping   | 2              | b               | Requirement 2b Camping |            |            |
+-----------+----------------+-----------------+------------------------+------------+------------+
```

*I substituted trailmanid for FirstName because I didn't include the trailman table above*

Comment: please post your expected result

Comment: Why are you using `[trailmanid]` syntax? That's for SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Comment: The woods Tools badge is easy to get. I'm surprised I don't have it already

Comment: Also, this is tagged MySQL, but you're not using MySQL, are you?

Comment: I was trying multiple systems so I probably just copied the query out of the wrong program (I think it might have been SQLite, I was desperate). The query didn't work on MySQL either (I duplicated the tables, data, and queries between them). I haven't tried MSSQL yet but I expect the same result.